Issue involving sum within query returning null values, and then 0 with the addition of Nz() even though there is a quantity (MS Access)
In MS Access, I have a query summing a quantities from one table, a union query summing hours from three different tables, and finally a third query joining these two queries through alike part numbers and part descriptions. When I do this, the summed hours for some of the part numbers comes back as null.
This is the SQL Code for the query that joins the two queries.
SELECT Quantity_Query.or_part_num,
  Quantity_Query.or_part_desc, 
  Nz(Sum(Per_Hours_Query.per_hours),0) AS Hours,
  Nz(Sum(Quantity_Query.ol_quantity),0) AS SumOfol_quantity
FROM Per_Hours_Query 
RIGHT JOIN Quantity_Query 
     ON (Per_Hours_Query.part_num = Quantity_Query.or_part_num) 
    AND (Per_Hours_Query.part_desc = Quantity_Query.or_part_desc)
GROUP BY Quantity_Query.or_part_num, Quantity_Query.or_part_desc

HAVING (((Quantity_Query.or_part_num) Like [Forms]![Part_Search]![PartNo_Search] & "*") 
   AND ((Quantity_Query.or_part_desc) Like [Forms]![Part_Search]![PartDesc_Search] & "*"))

ORDER BY Quantity_Query.or_part_num;

When I do the Nz() function, it comes back as 0 even though there are hours for most of the part numbers, while a very few come back with the correct amount. I need help as I am a beginner with MS Access, so any guidance would be appreciated.
The Per_Hours_Query
   SELECT pr_2022.run_date, pr_2022.part_num, pr_2022.part_desc, pr_2022.per_hours
   FROM pr_2022
    
   UNION
    
   SELECT pr_2023.run_date,pr_2023.part_num, pr_2023.part_desc, pr_2023.per_hours
   FROM pr_2023
    
   UNION 
   SELECT pr_2024.run_date, pr_2024.part_num, pr_2024.part_desc, pr_2024.per_hours
   FROM pr_2024;

The Quantity_Query:
SELECT r_22to24.ol_rel_date, 
  r_22to24.or_order_num, 
  r_22to24.or_part_num, 
  r_22to24.or_part_desc, 
  r_22to24.ol_quantity
FROM r_22to24
GROUP BY r_22to24.ol_rel_date, 
  r_22to24.or_order_num, 
  r_22to24.or_part_num, 
  r_22to24.or_part_desc, 
  r_22to24.ol_quantity;

Both queries pull from tables that contain the same set of part numbers/part descriptions, however each with their respective datas (hours and quantity produced)

without knowing the data sources it is impossible to say why some thing happen also please don't post images having a gzess you should start with the having  clause it filters too much ou

@nbk sorry about that. The having clause is just referring to a form that takes user input that I have created

like i said post the original data and table structures as needes in short create a [mre] for your problem and don't use images

@nbk Just edited my question and included the queries' code I pulled from in the original query I'm working on, as far as the data - refer to the piece at the end. Let me know if anything else is needed

I think, @Gustav answer is enough for your issue. You should provide data example.

Try with:
Sum(Nz(Per_Hours_Query.per_hours,0)) AS Hours, 
Sum(Nz(Quantity_Query.ol_quantity,0)) AS SumOfol_quantity


I just tried this, however it returns the same thing and still same issue occurring

Any other ideas by any chance?

Not without your data. Debug these carefully.
